# Merge and then Delete duplicate entries

Tags: mysql

I have mySQL database with some duplicate entries. They have the same field - phone. But they also had fields which differs. At example I have two entries with same phone, but first entry has rating filed = default_value and second entry has rating field = 5.
So I must merge this entries and only then delete duplicates...

More common example:

```
    entry1.phone==123
entry1.phone==etry2.phone
    entry1.rating!=entry2.phone
    entry1.rating==default_value(0)
    entry2.rating==5
    merge
    entry1.phone==123
    entry1.rating==5
    entry2 is deleted
```

Comment: i'm asking how to do this... sql query or stored routine...

Comment: But how would you determine which record you will delete? (Unless they're exact duplicates, but the way you ask suggests they're not...)

Comment: i will copy all(if it is not default_value) data into first duplicated entry and then delete all other duplicated entries.

i need to copy just three INT field from other entries, because other fields are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't really need to merge any records if you are just trying to update the first record with the non-default rating.  I think you can just delete any records with the default rating.

```
Select a.*
from tbl a
inner join tbl b
on a.Phone = b.Phone
    and a.Rating < b.Rating


Delete a
from tbl a
inner join tbl b
on a.Phone = b.Phone
    and a.Rating < b.Rating
```

If you truly have to update the first record and delete the second record, you can do something similar if you have an autoincrement ID.  The next example is what I would do to update the first record if an ID exists.  This is only reliable if you only have phone numbers duplicated one time.

```
Update a
Set a.Rating = b.Rating
from tbl a
inner join tbl b
on a.Phone = b.Phone
    and a.Rating < b.Rating
    and a.ID < b.ID


Delete a
from tbl a
inner join tbl b
on a.Phone = b.Phone
    and a.Rating = b.Rating
    and b.ID > a.ID
```

Hope this helps.

-Ranthalion

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this in SQL efficiently. One slow way to do it is something like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table (...);
INSERT INTO tmp_table SELECT phone, max(rating) FROM table GROUP BY phone;
TRUNCATE table;
INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM tmp_table;
```

A better way would be a stored procedure or an external script. Select all rows from the table ordered by `phone` and do the grouping/merging/deleting manually (iterate over the results, compare to the `phone` value from the previous row, if it's different you have a new group, etc.). Writing stored procedures in MySQL is painful though, so I'm not going to write the code for you. :)