# SQL QUERY: deleting duplicate rows from different tables with same columns

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables with the same columns (ID, name, etc.). But it appears that I have duplicate rows from both of them. I am supposed to move/copy the rows from table1 to table2 but it won't let me since I have a lot of duplicate rows and I can't get the right syntax to merge them properly.

I am using phpMyAdmin, btw.

Can someone help, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the command that you have tried?

Comment: I don't know if this would help..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577378/merge-and-then-delete-duplicate-entries

Comment: Well, I'm really new in SQL Queries and all of them are not working. Lol. I tried:

SELECT * 
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.id = table2.id

to view all those that I need to delete. But now I don't really know how to delete these.

I tried to simply do

DELETE * 
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.id = table2.id

though I'm kind of sure it's not the right syntax, but it's the one I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would simply like to delete the rows which are duplicates, do a `JOIN` like this:

```
DELETE table1.*
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.Id = table1.Id
```

Comment: THIS DID THE TRICK! THANK YOU VERY MUCH. :D I did not know INNER JOIN until now. I'll read more about this now for future use. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the `INSERT IGNORE` & `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: I get the idea, but still can't get to form the right syntax to INSERT from table1 to table2 and IGNORE the same rows. :(